# How to pass a string to /Home/Index in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

MVC newbie question in two parts, sooooo grateful if anyone can help:
1. How would I pass a string to this method (I want to append "?demo" to the URL and filter results on that basis):

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    List<NewItem> items = _service.GetItems(id == "demo");
    return View(items);
}
```

2. What's going on with id == "demo" passed in as an argument given that the method specifies a boolean (and it compiles and runs OK in this state):
    // This is the GetItems method
    public List GetItems(bool showDemo) { ... }
Finally here's my RegisterRoutes content:

```
routes.MapRoute(
       name: "itemtitle",
       url: "{Controller}/{action}/{id}/{itemtitle}",
       defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id =     UrlParameter.Optional,itemtitle=UrlParameter.Optional }
   );
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{Controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
    );
```

Comment: `id == "demo"` resolves to a boolean expression. Is ID == "demo" is a question with a yes or no answer.

Comment: also your url would be `MyController/Index/demo`, there wouldn't be a `?` anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this case:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Index(string id)
   {
       List<NewItem> items = _service.GetItems(id == "demo");
       return View(items);
   }
}
```

Then 3 ways:

1. `<baseurl>/Test/Index/12` -> using the id param
2. `<baseurl>/Test/Index?id=12` -> without the id param
3. `<baseurl>/Test?id=12` -> with the default action and without the param.

About the `id == "demo"` thing, this is a simple boolean condition:

```
"12" == "demo" -> false
"demo" == "demo" -> true
```